# Using a set method with pointers/classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to construct an object, and then set one of the variables to a value.

**Class header:**

```
class Book {
public:
Book();
Book(string newSelection);
string getSelection();
string setSelection(string newSelection);

private:
string selection;
}
```

**Class cpp**

```
Book::Book() {}

Book::Book(string newSelection) {
selection = newSelection;
}


string Book::getSelection(){
return selection;
}

string Book::setSelection(string newSelection){
selection = newSelection;
}
```

**Driver**

```
Book* book1 = new Book();
book1->setSelection("The Book Title");
cout << "Book selected:    " << book1->getSelection() << endl;
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault, and am not sure why.  Can somebody point out where my problem may be?

Comment: This code looks perfectly fine. Are you sure this is all? And this gives you seg-fault?

Comment: Try it without a pointer, so Book book1; Then book1.setSelection("Book Title"); does that work? Also are you remembering to include string? However your code is fine, and it should work.

Comment: You are also missing a `;` after the `}` in the class definition in the header file, but this should come up as a compiler error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setSelection()` function is declared as returning a string but no string is actually being returned. You should get a compile warning at least for this.

From running this through in a debugger, I *believe* that what's happening is that following the call to `setSelection()` the destructor is called on the returned string. As this string does not really exist, this causes an `abort()` within the runtime.

As a general rule, 'setters' tend not to return anything so would be written as follows:

```
void setSelection(const string& newSelection);
```

...

```
void Book::setSelection(const string& newSelection)
{
    selection = newSelection;
}
```

also note that the string is passed in by const reference rather than by value which is more efficient. This won't be the cause of your problem though.

Another suggestion would be to ensure that your 'getter' is declared const as it doesn't change anything in the object:

```
string getSelection() const;
```

...

```
string Book::getSelection() const
{
    return selection;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. the return value is never used, but still - you may be right?

Comment: I just worked it out.  I have spent over an hour looking at this.  Yes... the problem was returning a string in the setSelection function.  I changed this to void, and it works! YAY.  Thanks everybody :)

Comment: More hunch than science. True enough when I compiled it I got `warning: control reaches end of non-void function` which is what I'd expect. I ran it through gdb and I've added my thoughts in above based on what I found.

Comment: First time I've seen this.  I'm pretty certain that I've got software that does this - when copy/pasting a getter to add a setter it's very easy to return something that's not used and get a system that works, (with GCC anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The `setSelection` method is defined as returning a string, yet it is not returning anything.  Perhaps adding a return statement (or changing it to void) will fix it:

```
string Book::setSelection(string newSelection){
  selection = newSelection;
  return selection;
}
```

Comment: Compilers are not required to warn on failure to return a value, as in general it's difficult to tell whether all paths are reachable.